I installed Nuxt today and I am trying to work with local host but, it is not working as the localhost is constantly in loading
I've selected Nuxt as my first framework. Installing was not the issue, documentation was very concise.
When I started my project, prepared everything up I started the dev using command npx nuxi dev got the local link. At first, it worked but as I restarted WebStorm I saw that local host did not work correctly. It keeps loading for 30 mints by now. I don't know what to do.
I tried to get a new local host link, tried restarting WebStorm, tried to restart my Windows. I don't know what else I should do.


Webstorm is a text editor so far, how is it related? Are you launching it via some shell in it? If that's the case, try to launch it out of the shell. What are you using on Windows? Also, do you have any errors in the console? Can you try another browser, like Chrome, and double-check if you do not have any plugins blocking it? The HMR reload should be quite instant for a brand new project.
